# How to unlock my phone using my voice?

Tags: android

i want my app to unlock my phone using my voice i already implemented a method that converts speech to text and i made a broadcast reciever to listen for "screen on event" to call my recognize method in main activity but when i say the password nothing happens.

**this is my mainactivity class:-**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_OUTPUT = 143;
private Button btnSave, btnTry;
private ImageButton btnRecord;
private TextView tvResult;
private SharedPreferences userData;
private String password;
private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;
    btnSave = findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    btnTry = findViewById(R.id.btn_try_again);
    tvResult = findViewById(R.id.tv_word_entered);
    btnRecord =findViewById(R.id.btn_record);
    btnTry.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnSave.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    tvResult.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);




    userData = this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.shared_prefrence_name), MODE_PRIVATE);

    btnTry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            recognize('s' ,i);
        }
    });



    //register the receiver
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new MYBROADCAST();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    registerReceiver(receiver,filter);


}//end of onCreate

//start listening to the user
public void startRecording(View view) {
    //recognize the voice to be stored
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    recognize('s' , i);
} //end of startRecording

public void recognize(char c , Intent intent) {

    //intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());

    if(c == 'u')
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"Say the password to unlock your device");
    else
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"Say the password you want to add");


    try{
        startActivityForResult(intent,REQ_CODE_SPEECH_OUTPUT);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
        Log.d("voice","error in taking speech to text");
    }

} //end of on recognize

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data){

    //speeach to Text is done here
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    switch (requestCode){
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_OUTPUT: {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
                ArrayList<String> voiceInText = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                btnTry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnRecord.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                password = voiceInText.get(0);
                tvResult.setText(voiceInText.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }
    }

}// end of on Activity result


//check user credentials
public void CheckCredentials(Intent intent){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i< count;i++){
        recognize('u' , intent);  //app crashes here
        if( password == userData.getString("user_pass",null)){
            //unlock the phone
            KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            final KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = km .newKeyguardLock("MyKeyguardLock");
            kl.disableKeyguard();
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                    | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                    | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");
            wakeLock.acquire();
        }

        else{
            count++;
        }
    }
} // end of CheckCredentials


//saving user Credentials
public void SaveCredentials(View view) {
    //save the user cedintial in a shared by refrence
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userData.edit();
    editor.putString(getString(R.string.user_password), password);
    editor.commit();
    Toast.makeText(context, "Password Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}//end of save credintials
```

}//end of class MainActivity

**and here is my broadcast reciever class :-**

```
public class MYBROADCAST extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "unlocked";
private MainActivity instance;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    instance = new MainActivity();
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
        Log.d(TAG, "Phone unlocked");
        //Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        instance.CheckCredentials(i);
    }
}
```

}